# Problems migrating Node.js Azure Function from Function Extensions 2.x to 3.x

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

So, I've inherited an Azure Function App written in Node.js from a contractor who did a little work for us. This piece of code was developed outside our C# stack, so I'm having to go back and maintain it.

I'm trying to update the Azure Function Extensions runtime for the project in Visual Studio Code, however it seems to be ignoring the local.settings.json for my development environment, and no matter which flags I set, it continues to run the 2.x runtime.

[image: local.settings.json]

And when it runs, I'm seeing the following errors:

[image: old version warning]

However the [documentation](https://aka.ms/func-v2-upgrade) they're referencing has zero information about migrating from 2.x to 3.x other than that it 'will be seemless in most cases'.

And of course, the function app won't run:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being the version of the core tools running on my development VM.

As per the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash%2Ckeda#v2), the core tools version needs to be installed (x64 version for VS Code).

In spite of the fact that I setup this Dev VM yesterday, it still needed to have the core tools version updated to the latest. Once I updated it, it was able to spin up the function locally as expected.